# Repeat a method in Java? / Rotating pictures

Tags: java, image, rotation

I have a method already to rotate a picture 90 degrees, but I need to write a separate one to rotate it 180 degrees, and another for 270 degrees. I thought I could do this by repeating the 90 degree one, but I'm new at this and don't really know.

**My 90 degree code:**

```
    public Picture rotateRight90()
  {
   Picture rotated = new Picture (getHeight(), getWidth());

   for (int x = 0, roty = 0; x < getWidth(); x++, roty++)
   {
    for ( int y = 0, rotx = getHeight() - 1; y < getHeight(); y++, rotx--)
    {
       Pixel orig = getPixel(x,y);
       Pixel rotPix = rotated.getPixel (rotx, roty);
       rotPix.setColor(orig.getColor());
    }
   }
   return rotated;
  }
```

**My attempted rotate 180 code:**

```
     public Picture rotate180()
 {
   Picture rotated = new Picture (getHeight(), getWidth());

   for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
   {
     for (int x = 0, roty = 0; x < getWidth(); x++, roty++)
   {
    for ( int y = 0, rotx = getHeight() - 1; y < getHeight(); y++, rotx--)
    {
       Pixel orig = getPixel(x,y);
       Pixel rotPix = rotated.getPixel (rotx, roty);
       rotPix.setColor(orig.getColor());
    }
   }
   }
   return rotated;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating the code from rotateRight90 into rotate180, couldn't you could just call rotateRight90 twice from rotate180? (And 3 times from rotate270)

Comment: Your functions don't take `Picture` as input, so how can you change what Picture is rotated?  If it took input, you can pass in the returned value into the function again to do the 2nd, 3rd, Xth rotation.

Comment: If you need to rotate image 180 degrees you just need to call `rotateRight90()` method **(180/90) 2** times and for 270 degree rotation you need to call `rotateRight90()` method **(270/90) 3** times. You should be able to get it done from here.

Comment: what gla3dr and Prateek said, but regarding your code: note that rotating a 100x50 image by 90° results in 50x100, but 180° again in 100x50. also, you declare `rotated` outside the loop and always read from `this`, so both executions of the loop do the same thing. it kind of like `j = i + 1; j = i + 1;`: the second execution does the same thing as the first and doesn't add to the overall result

Comment: I'm in a beginning programming class, how would you go about calling the method X times? I appreciate your help

Comment: @Walls: Java is OO, so there sort of is an implicit `this` parameter that `getHeight()`, `getWidth()` and `getPixel()` operate on (as opposed to e.g. `rotated.getPixel()`, which operates on `rotated`)

Comment: @SillyFreak I was assuming it was not this way, since the OP is returning a value instead of having `void` method that rotates `this`.  If they were `void` I would have assumed it was rotating the current class, but the `return` of data is what makes it not quite clear on the intended functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is one for 180

```
  public Picture rotateRight180()
{
  Picture rotated = new Picture (getWidth(), getHeight());
 
  for (int x = 0, rotx = getWidth() - 1; x < getWidth(); x++, rotx--)
  {
    for (int y = 0, roty = getHeight() - 1; y < getHeight (); y++, roty--)
   {
     
      Pixel orig = getPixel (x,y);
      Pixel rotPix = rotated.getPixel (rotx, roty);
      rotPix.setColor(orig.getColor());
   
   }
  }
  return rotated;
 }
```